# Access a website on phone with backend server using expressJS and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, socket.io

I'm building a web application with a backend server using express.js based on the Spotify Web API. Following the [tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/) in their documentation, I added socket.io to the project to communicate between front- and back-end.
Now I'm so far along in the development process that I really need to test how the website appears and functions on devices other than my computer, such as a phone (I use an Android).

I've tried accessing the website by going to `http://<Local IP Address>:<port number>` on my phone's browser as described [here](https://prowe214.medium.com/tip-how-to-view-localhost-web-apps-on-your-phone-ad6b2c883a7c). Though I can view the site, no connection is established to the backend via socket. How can this be done?
All other research I did led more or less to Android apps using express, but I'm really building more of a dynamic website...

The code below should give you an idea of what I'm doing on the backend. Despite coding for a few years now, I am quite new to server-side programming, which is why I, admittedly, don't really understand my code below all too well (the authorization flow I do understand; it's just express and socket.io, where I don't know what is happening).

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cors = require('cors');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const app = express();

const { client_id, client_secret } = require('./credentials.json')
const
  redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback',
  scopes = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-library-read user-library-modify',
  stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

var access_token;
var refresh_token;


function generateRandomString(length) { ... }

app
  .use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'))
  .use(cors())
  .use(cookieParser());


app.get('/login', function (req, res) {

  const state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(stateKey, state);

  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scopes,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));
});

app.get('/callback', function (req, res) {

  const code = req.query.code || null,
    state = req.query.state || null,
    storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;


  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {

    res.redirect('/login_callback.html#' +
      querystring.stringify({
        error: 'state_mismatch'
      }));

  } else {

    res.clearCookie(stateKey);
    const authOptions = {
      url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      form: {
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      },
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
      },
      json: true
    }

    request.post(authOptions, function (error, response, body) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        access_token = body.access_token;
        refresh_token = body.refresh_token;
        res.redirect('/login_callback.html');

      } else {

        res.redirect('/login_callback.html#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            error: 'invalid_token'
          }));
      }
    });
  }

});


const server = app.listen(8888, () => console.log('Listening on 8888'));
const io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log('Made socket connection on ' + socket.handshake.time);
  if (access_token) socket.emit('access', access_token)


  socket.on("access_token_request", () => socket.emit('access', access_token))

...


});
```

Any insights as to how to finally see that 'Made socket connection on ...' after opening the site on my phone is much appreciated!